# amazon s3 upload signed url public-read

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

This is the URL generated by the [Ruby aws-sdk gem](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/) for put:

```
curl --upload-file "/Users/README.rdoc" 
-H "x-amz-acl=public-read" 
"http://videos.s3.amazonaws.com/6c06517c-64f1-45ed-b07f-8c4c4edec6e3?AWSAccessKeyId={key}&Expires=1384519899&Signature=MKtBESBklYXFT%2B48EKLSoBiQpNA%3D"
```

`-H "x-amz-acl=public-read"` is not present in the signature. The signature is OK (Amazon doesn't show any errors).

But the "public-read" permission is not applied, please advise me as to how I can generate a put signed URL which will be public-read after upload.

Thanks!

Updated:

```
s3 = AWS::S3.new
bucket = s3.buckets['some_videos']
id = SecureRandom.uuid
object = bucket.objects["#{id}"]
url = object.url_for(:put, expires_in: 30*60)
```

Comment: Could you please add the Ruby code that you're using that generates this URL?

Comment: @carols10cents done, please look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon team added this to their sdk. Thanks, guys!
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/412
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/commit/15e900c0918a67e20bbb6dd9509c112aa01a95ee

Answer (score 3):

it looks like you can specify this with the acl method (documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#acl=-instance_method))
If you want to set your bucket to public read you can call:

```
s3.buckets['some-videos'].acl = :public_read
```

if you would like to apply this permission directly to an object you can call:

```
bucket.objects["#{id}"].acl= :public_read
```

Comment: Neal, it looks like SDK v2 takes a string "public-read"

obj.upload_file(fd, {
            :acl => "public-read"
        })